# KSP Initial Throttle Value at 50%

Tags: kerbal-space-program

Is there a way to make it so that the initial throttle setting is zero? As of 0.24.2 (maybe .1 as well) my throttle starts at 50%.

Comment: A quick look through the config file seems to indicate that no, this can't be changed, at least not by stock methods.

Comment: you can press `X` to zero your throttle at any time in the flight screen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In version 1.2.2, this can be configured in the settings

[image]

Move the slider to the left to turn the default throttle to 0%, turn it to the right to make it 100%

Comment: I love how KSP is still in active development.

Answer (score 0):

The only method I found may be a bit costly, but it works: Connect a joystick or gamepad with analog controller that can be used as throttle, set it to 0 and configure to be Kerbal's throttle control. Then you can just leave it there - on load Kerbal will set throttle to physical position of your joystick's throttle, but it will allow you to use keyboard controls as long as you are not moving joystick's one.

For your purpose it may even be a broken one, as long as it is recognized and reports throttle off. Of course I prefer just to use it, when I have enough space on my desk ;) But I had to unplug my joystick to notice the effect you described, so yes, I know just having it connected will work for you. Unless, of course, they will change it in next minor release...

Comment: Doesn't work for me: The throttle only changes when I move the throttle control of my joystick.

Comment: @Philipp so either 1) My installation was not yet updated when I tested, or 2) Somehow either my joystick is different, or Linux version works differently. Can't really tell. Sorry it does not work. I'm prepared to delete it if it's worthless, but let's give it some time for OP to see, and for me to ensure my version is current and re-test.

Comment: Looks like that might be the only option. I suspect that different joysticks respond differently to when they send their input (eg throttle value). I hope that this feature is changed in a soon-to-come patch. One other solution (I suspect) would be a mod that simply sets the game throttle to 0 when a craft is loaded.

Comment: @MrUniverse Probably you're right with that "different joysticks" as it works for me so far. I don't think it *should* be the only way, but it seems it is. Also, I believe that *not* setting throttle to what physical control device is set to may be considered a bug.